# Underlying Logic for Count Function in SQL

Tags: sql, mysql, count

While working on Leetcode, I raised this question. It is for Q1633.
Why the code in pic cannot return proper number of count. I noticed for the numerator it cannot change with the group by clause. Could anyone explain it to me? I am an analyst and haven't learnt about the back logic.

[image]

The question of Leetcode posted here:

[image]

Comment: Post the code and schema here, not images.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please read this guide on how to ask question.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

The correct query is

```
select Round(100 * part_cnt / cnt, 2) as percentage
from
(select count(*) as cnt from Users) t1,
(
    select count(*) as part_cnt, contest_id
    from Register
    group by contest_id
) t2
order by percentage desc, contest_id;
```

Explanation:

- we count the number of users as a subquery for `t1`
- we count the number of registers for each contest as `t2` to know the participants (assuming that there are no duplicates in Register)
- we compute the division and round the result

Since you have grouped by `contest_id`, counts upon it will yield its value.

Comment: Great. So now we have an answer, but we don't have a proper question.